# Program installation problems on Windows Guest

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box 4.3.6 r91406 on my Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed Windows 7 Ultimate and Red Hat Enterprise Linux as the guest operating systems. I have also installed the Virtual Box Guest Additions on Windows 7 Guest and have also configured my desired shared folder. I am able to access all the files but can't run or install any program on Windows Guest as I am always greeted with the error :

" The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again. "

Please help! Urgent.

Comment: You could get better results if you ask this on a Windows forum. This looks like a Windows error to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually a problem when running .exe files from a virtual box shared folder on the windows guest. The solution is to run the .exe using UNC paths ie In your Explorer (in Windows) go to \Vboxsvr\your shared folder\path\to\folder\with\exe and run the .exe from there.

Here's some more info on that: http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm

Comment: Don't you need "\\" in the beginnning? i.e. \\Vboxsvr\your shared folder\path\...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create a new FOLDER on the local hard drive in win 7 virtualbox it. copy and paste the programs you like in FOLDER it. After that you can install the program.

Answer (score 0):

First connect the share from Virtual box's side. Then when mapping (at least from Win7 x64 this works) tick the box that says "other credentials." This solved it for me.